# Google Sheets - When clicking on a checkbox, I want the row to be cleared (not deleted), and also for the checkbox to then reset

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've been trying to figure this one out and I'm a bit lost...

This is what I have so far:

```
function deleteCheckedBoxes() {

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

const activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
const activeRow = activeRange.getRow();
const activeColumn = activeRange.getColumn();

let rangeUpdatedValue =  activeRange.getValue();

if(activeColumn == 5 && rangeUpdatedValue == true){

 sheet.deleteRow(activeRow);

};
  
}
```

How can I get it to clear the row instead of deleting it?

I have tried clearContent & ClearContents, but it doesn't seem to work

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheet.deleteRow(activeRow);
```

#### To:

```
sheet.getRange(activeRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
```

- When this modified script is run, the row of the active range is cleared.
- In this case, by `clearContent()`, the checkbox is unchecked.

#### Reference:

- [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent)

Comment: YOU ARE A GOD! Thank you so much for your help, I'm very new to this so I was pulling my hair out!

Did exactly what it needed to do!

My account is too new to vote, but I will vote as soon as my account hits the required rep.

Comment: @Matthew Butera Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteCheckedBoxes() {

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

const activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
const activeRow = activeRange.getRow();
const activeColumn = activeRange.getColumn();

let rangeUpdatedValue =  activeRange.getValue();

if(activeColumn == 5 && rangeUpdatedValue == true){

 sheet.getRange(activeRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();


};
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.